# Cannot create partition table on my memory card, therefore cant format it using any tool

Tags: usb, partitioning, sd-card

I think I have tried everything , but I am a virgin linux user and I may not have tried the right things.
I am trying to format my memory card using fdisk , every thing goes to plan, but when I excute the w command, and it says

> The partition table has been altered.
>   Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
>   Syncing disks.

but then when I try `mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/sdc1` , I get

> mkfs.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
>   mkfs.vfat: unable to open /dev/sdc1: No such file or directory

then I go `fdisk /dev/sdc`
I get

> Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.32.1).
>   Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
>   Be careful before using the write command.
>   Device does not contain a recognized partition table.
>   Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0x288f5b3c.

and it goes on and on every time I create a partition using fdisk , and it goes well in there, after I write on disk the partitions get deleted and I dont know why 
aslo this is what `dmesg | tail` gives me :

```
[ 6304.554564] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 6304.554822] scsi host4: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[ 6305.866892] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     MXT-USB  Storage Device   1308 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[ 6305.921818] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 6305.952438] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] 11981824 512-byte logical blocks: (6.13 GB/5.71 GiB)
[ 6305.955411] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[ 6305.955414] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[ 6305.959923] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[ 6305.959927] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 6306.514638] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

---

Edit : output of `lsblk -i --include 8`

> NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
>   sda      8:0    0   20G  0 disk 
>   |-sda1   8:1    0   18G  0 part /
>   `-sda5   8:5    0    2G  0 part [SWAP]
>   sdc      8:32   1  5.7G  0 disk

and output of `fdisk --list`

> Disk /dev/sda: 20 GiB, 21474836480 bytes, 41943040 sectors
>   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disklabel type: dos
>   Disk identifier: 0xca1f41c0
>   Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
>   /dev/sda1  *        2048 37750783 37748736  18G 83 Linux
>   /dev/sda2       37752830 41940991  4188162   2G  5 Extended
>   /dev/sda5       37752832 41940991  4188160   2G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
>   Disk /dev/sdc: 5.7 GiB, 6134693888 bytes, 11981824 sectors
>   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Edit: I have tried gparted but I cant get it to create partition table; here is what gparted look like [gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdA9H.png)

---

Edit: I have tried formating using `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=512 count=1`
 and then I view the results using `dd if=/dev/sdc bs=512 count=1 | hexdump -C` which should give me zeros , but it didnt!
after that I used `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=1M`
and it actually gave me zeros this time; here

> 00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
>   *
>   00000200
>   1+0 records in
>   1+0 records out
>   512 bytes copied, 0.00445352 s, 115 kB/s

Edit: I tried to check for bad blocks; with `badblocks -vw /dev/sdc' and I get

> Pass completed, 5990912 bad blocks found. (0/0/5990912 errors)

I know its not worth the effort, I am just using this to learn, so thanks for your time and effort in advance!

---

Edit: I tried gsmartcontrol , it doesnt allow me to perform tests, and here is what it gives

> smartctl 6.6 2017-11-05 r4594 [x86_64-linux-4.18.0-kali2-amd64] (local build)
>   Copyright (C) 2002-17, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               MXT-USB
Product:              Storage Device
Revision:             1308
User Capacity:        6,134,693,888 bytes [6.13 GB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
scsiModePageOffset: response length too short, resp_len=4 offset=4 bd_len=0
scsiModePageOffset: response length too short, resp_len=4 offset=4 bd_len=0

> > Terminate command early due to bad response to IEC mode page
> >     A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.

Comment: Edit your question, cursor to the end, press CTRL+R, then add the output of `lsblk -i --include 8` and `sudo fdisk --list` to your post. Set "code-sample" on the text printed by the commands.